# .gitignore file for java eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git

I have java project that uses the Eclipse IDE.

The Eclipse workspace is pointing to this directory:

```
/home/srvimgprd/BUSPROJ/code_development/dime/executables/clientcode/java_axis/Eclipse
```

I have placed a `.gitignore` file in **the workspace directory** "Eclipse". See below.

What I need to do is to be able to download the items from the Eclipse directory onto a new machine and then compile with no issue.

Are there any concrete steps to accomplish this task? When using the `.gitignore` file below, nothing shows up on the target machine.

---

CONTENTS OF ECLIPSE DIRECTORY (on **source** machine):
/home/srvimgprd/BUSPROJ/code_development/dime/executables/clientcode/java_axis/Eclipse

---

```
java_axis/Eclipse> ls -lart
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 2 imgdev development 4096 2013-09-09 04:53 RemoteSystemsTempFiles
drwxr-xr-x 4 imgdev development 4096 2013-09-09 04:55 Servers
drwxr-xr-x 4 imgdev development 4096 2013-09-09 04:58 .metadata
drwxr-xr-x 6 imgdev development 4096 2013-09-09 05:06 Axis2ClientDimeServer
drwxr-xr-x 5 imgdev development 4096 2013-09-10 08:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 imgdev development  307 2013-09-10 08:31 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 6 imgdev development 4096 2013-09-10 08:31 .
```

---

CONTENTS OF .gitignore FILE

---

```
*target*
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.class

# eclipse specific git ignore
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

put .gitignore in your main catalog

```
git status (you will see which files you can commit)
git add -A
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your source files with `git add` or the GUI equivalent so that Git will begin tracking them.

Use `git status` to see what Git thinks about the files in any given directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) This much I understand. I use git-gui to pick out what needs to be sent up and what does not. For me, the problem was choose enough of the right eclipse files so that when I pull down the eclipse java project onto on "fresh" system, I could start up eclipse, compile and then run the program. Is it actually possible to do this?

Comment: Looking for a good .gitignore template for eclipse as well, this may help [Eclipse.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/Eclipse.gitignore), obviously you then need to tweak it O_o